# css custom cursor problems

Tags: html, css

I just started coding, don't judge me if I say stupid things. I'm trying to make a costume cursor for my website but it doesn't work in any way. I've even set the image size, which is 32x32 pixels. [This is the picture I tried to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDrS2.png)

I doesn't work and not just with this image: I even tried with other ones, png and svg. 
I used both "pointer" and "auto" but nothing.
Not working on Safari and not working on Chrome.
Can someone help me please?
Thank you so much!
My code is

`body{background-color: #F3F1EB; cursor: url("plane.png"), pointer;}`

Comment: Is your plane.png image in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is fine therefore I can only imagine it is one of the following problems:

1. The plane.png image is not in the same folder as your .html file
2. The plane.png image is larger than 32x32 pixels
3. You have not enclosed your CSS in `<style></style>` tags
4. You don't have any content within your `<body>` tag therefore the CSS isn't trigggering

This is tested and works:

```
<html>
    <style>
        html {
        background-color: #F3F1EB; 
        cursor: url('plane.png'), pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
       //Your page contents here
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: I used the HTML selector for test purposes.

Final point - changing the cursor to a custom image is bad practice for a number of reasons. Mainly, it negatively affects the UX of a site.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the picture is located in the right folder. I use the full path of the picture you gave, it is working.

```css
body{
  background-color: #F3F1EB; 
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDrS2.png"), pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!! Do it at the CSS level:

```
* {
   cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDrS2.png"), pointer;
}
```